# Array del tipo AnyObject a un arreglo Json usando swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo de applicaciones para IOS y estoy usando swift, necesito generar un arreglo Json como este:

```
{
  "PaymentItems": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "paid": false
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "paid": false
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "paid": false
    }
  ]
}
```

para lograr lo antes mencionado estoy usando este bloque de codigo, hasta el momento sin exito.

```
var elementos = [AnyObject]()
for item in transacciones_modificacion
{
  let jsonObjectPaid: [AnyObject]  = [[ "id": item.Id, "paid":  item.Paid]]
elementos.append(jsonObjectPaid)
}    
let pagosArray = ["PaymentItems": [elementos]]
```

en un arreglo como este:

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varios errores de concepto. Para resumir, el código correcto sería:

```
var elementos = [AnyObject]()
for item in transacciones_modificacion
{
    let jsonObjectPaid = ["id": item.Id, "paid": item.Paid]
    elementos.append(jsonObjectPaid)
}
let pagosArray = ["PaymentItems": elementos]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias mhergon, me funciono a la perfeccion